# Is the method filesystem.findinfiles available to ".xlsx" file ?

Tags: excel, vb.net, findinfiles

I am intending to write a sub to loop through a directory to find is there any file (xls, xlsx, txt, etc.) which contains the input sting。

I used filesystem.findinfiles method, but it seems that xlsx files couldn't be read with this method. ( I have done some tests, a xlsx file which contains the string could not be listed in the result)

I am thankful to any ideas or suggestions~

below is my code :

```
Dim Flist As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)

Flist = My.Computer.FileSystem.FindInFiles("C:/some directory/", "inputstring", True,FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly)

For Each Names In Flist
     foundlist.Add(Names)
next
```

Comment: Do you want to list all the files that contain the inputstring no matter where it is? or do you have any idea where the string could be located?

Comment: To read file contents like this, you should look in to the IFilter interface. I know it is implemented by companies for PDF, MSG, DOC/X, XLS/X, and TXT

Comment: @Dknacht1 Basically, yes, exclude file name. For example the string should be located a certain cell in a xls, xlsx file。

Comment: @JayV thank you for the advise, I would look in to it, IFilter interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need .GetFiles. .FindInFiles is looking in the file itself, not the name of the file.

```
Flist = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Excel", FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.xlsx")
```

Notice that the parameters are in a different order and the Boolean value is not required.

Comment: but I want to check out whether those files contains this string or not, not the file name.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I find the same as you, it reads .xls just fine but not .xlsx.

Comment: To Mary : thank you for the testing, it seems that filesystem.findinfiles could not work for xlsx.